# Get only unique value in array by case sensative

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I want unique array from an array by comparing all values to lower case or upper case so i can get perfect array.suppose you have two values in array like 'php developer' and 'Php Developer', both are same so i need returning array which just contain one value and its 'Php Developer'.

```
array('php developer','Php Developer');
```

i need this array as follows :

```
array('Php Developer')
```

I want unique array from an array by comparing all values to lower case or upper case so i can get perfect array.suppose you have two values in array like 'php developer' and 'Php Developer', both are same so i need returning array which just contain one value and its 'Php Developer'.

Comment: yes i have done by using array_unique function but its not checking values by case sensitive it returns both

Answer (score 0):

`array_unique()` is case-sensitive, so `Php Developer` and `php developer` is not the same - and therefor not unique - in the eyes of that function.

You should therefor convert the entire array to lowercase using `array_map()` with the `strtolower()` callback, and then do the `array_unique()` on that.

```php
$array = array_unique(array_map('strtolower', array('php developer','Php Developer')));
print_r($array); // Outputs 'php developer'
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/d92Lf

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo Link**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27409d37b64fed15ceb9caf3c0318268545e8cdc).

You can use this function to filter case insensitive values from an array.

**Method 1:**

```
function array_iunique($array) {  // Case insensitive
    // lower all array cases of array values
    $lowered = array_map('strtolower', $array); 
    // will fetch unique array first means php developer
    // now array_intersect_key will return first match value for php developer
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_unique($lowered));
}
```

**Method 2:** faster than the above method

```
function array_iunique($array) { 
    return array_keys(array_flip(array_map('strtolower',$array))); 
}
```

**Method 3:** more faster

```
function array_iunique($array) { 
    return array_flip(array_flip(array_map('strtolower',$array))); 
}
```

[array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays
[array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) — Computes the intersection of arrays using keys for comparison
[array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) — Exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array
[array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) — Merge one or more arrays
[array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

> Note that keys are preserved. If multiple elements compare equal under
>   the given sort_flags, then the key and value of the first equal
>   element will be retained.
>
> **Note:** Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2` i.e. when the string representation is the
>   same, the first element will be used.

Source [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#78801).

Comment: I ran some local benchmarks against the 3 methods you have, and the one I have in my answer - I was curious which would be faster and better. With an iteration of 10.000.000, each run 3 times to get a minor average, and your second method is in fact the fastest one of your three methods, by 1 second for ten million executions. (13.6 seconds to 14.6 for your two other methods, one and three). My answer had an average execution time of 13.3 seconds, and arguably more easy to read :-) Just thought I'd share my findings. Solid answer though, there's many ways to Rome.. :-)

Comment: Why do you have `array_merge()` in method 3 by the way? You're not merging it with anything. Removing it in my benchmark reduced it from 14.6 to 14.2 seconds for 10 million executions, without change of result!

Comment: @Qirel Thank you. I made changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative using good old `foreach` and the fact that associative arrays can only have 1 value per key, this just adds in all the items to an array with the key set to the lower case version...

```
$data = array('php developer','Php Developer');
$out = [];
foreach ( $data as $item )  {
    $out[strtolower($item)] = $item;
}
print_r($out);
```

If you don't need the key at the end, you can use...

```
$out = array_values($out);
```